# Connect to postgresql database in docker with pgadmin and nginx on the server

Tags: postgresql, docker, nginx, pgadmin

I'm having trouble connecting to the postgresql database with pgadmin. The postgresql database is on a remote server and it is implemented in a docker composer container. The pgadmin is in local.

The problem is that I can't register or connect to the postgrest server from my local
The database credentials are fine so it's a configuration issue I guess.

The following configuration is the configuration that I have of nginx and of docker-compose.yml

Is it possible that I am missing to co-configure in nignx.conf a new location /?

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    index index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxx.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxx.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backendcallservices:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    http2_push_preload on;

}
```

This is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  webservercallservices:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: webserver-callservices
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - backendcallservices
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./Dockerfiles/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt 
    networks:
      app-network:

  backendcallservices:
    build:
      context: ./Dockerfiles/python
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: sh -c 'python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - databasecallservices
      - redis
    networks:
      app-network:
    
  databasecallservices:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      app-network:

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      app-network:

networks:
  app-network:
```